# Convert list-like object to data frame with columns

Tags: r

I would like to convert the following object to a data frame with 7 columns. Some of the rows in the example contains 6 strings (separated by a space), and some 7 (row #3). For those that contains 6, we should just put NA in the 7th column.
I have tried `unlist` and similar, but it did not work properly.

```
   structure(list(`my_list` = c("hsa_miR_942_5p -0.01020 0.98986 0.04543 -0.224 0.822", 
    "hsa_miR_95_3p -0.05272 0.94864 0.04607 -1.145 0.252", "hsa_miR_96_5p -0.14028 0.86912 0.04114 -3.410 0.00065 ***", 
    "hsa_miR_98_5p -0.06664 0.93554 0.05587 -1.193 0.233", "hsa_miR_99a_5p -0.02230 0.97795 0.04625 -0.482 0.630", 
    "hsa_miR_99b_5p 0.01528 1.01539 0.04502 0.339 0.734")), row.names = 344:349, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It seems you read the data incorrectly. You could/should fix the issue while reading itself (by using appropriate separator) . if you want to do it based on the data that you have now use `splitstackshape::cSplit(df, 'my_list', sep = ' ')` which splits the data into 7 columns.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But what do you mean by read incorrectly?

Comment: I did the following to create this example data, maybe the error is here: as.data.frame(gsub("\\s+", " ", df)  )

Comment: How did you get `df` ? Did you read it from csv file? How did you read it?

Comment: From a coxph object: df <-   as.matrix(as.list(coxph)[grep("hsa", as.list(coxph))])